# How do I create a color plot that varies with angle?

Tags: plotting, color

I want to create a plot with a hue that varies as $l\theta$. $l$ is an integer and $\theta$ is measured modulo $2\pi$. My specific case is $l=10$, but I want to be able to vary $l$ as well.

I have naively tried

```
l=10;
DensityPlot[l ArcTan[x,y],{x,-4,4},{y,-4,4}]
```

This code produces

[http://people.oregonstate.edu/~thomasky/ky-images/messed-up-visualization.png http://people.oregonstate.edu/~thomasky/ky-images/messed-up-visualization.png](http://people.oregonstate.edu/~thomasky/ky-images/messed-up-visualization.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is sort of covered in the documentation (see `Hue` and the `ColorFunction` option in `DensityPlot`), but here's probably what you're looking for:

```
l = 10;
DensityPlot[l ArcTan[x, y], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, 
 ColorFunction -> (Hue[#/(2 \[Pi])] &), ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
  PlotPoints -> 150]
```

which produces:

[image]

Alternately, you can generate it as a complex phase-magnitude plot of $\exp(i\arg(z^{10}))$, as follows:

```
ComplexPlotC[CCompileC[E^(I Arg[z^10])], {-2, 2, 0.01}, {-2, 2, 0.01}, 1]
```

which produces:

[image]

using the custom plotting method for functions $f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ defined below:

```
hue = Compile[{{z, _Complex}}, {(1.0 Arg[-z] + π)/(2 π), 
    Exp[1 - Max[Abs[z], 1]], Min[Abs[z], 1]}, 
   CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}];
ComplexPlotC[f_, {x0_, x1_, δx_}, {y0_, y1_, δy_}, 
   mag_] := 
  Image[hue[
     mag f[Outer[Complex, Range[x0, x1, δx], 
        Range[y1, y0, -δy]]]]\[Transpose], ColorSpace -> Hue, 
   Magnification -> 1];
CCompileC[expr_] := 
  Compile[{{z, _Complex}}, Evaluate[expr], CompilationTarget -> "C", 
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want something like this:

```
f[x_, y_] := Norm[{x, y}] ArcTan[x, y]
CoolColor[ z_ ] := RGBColor[z, 1 - z, 1]
Show[DensityPlot[f[x, y], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, PlotPoints -> 50, ColorFunction -> CoolColor],
     ContourPlot[f[x, y], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, PlotPoints -> 50, 
                 Contours -> 20, ColorFunction -> (Transparent &)]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]